# angular child state is not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state("board", {
    url:"/board/:type",
    templateUrl: "boardListPlain.jsp",
    controller: 'BoardController',
    controllerAs : 'board'
})
 .state("boardInsert", {
    url:"/board/:type/insert",
    templateUrl: "boardInsert.html"
})
```

In this stateProvider /board/:type/insert shows /board//insert
I know this is ridiculous way to do. but I don't know how to handle ":type"
I've tried child state but it seems need some specific named view.
And please recommend me some good place to learn basic skills of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should declare two state and in which the `insert` state would be the child state of the `board` state, As you are following nested state you need to declare child state by `parentName.childName` notation. Here it becomes `board.insert`

Whenever you wanted to call the board state you need to call `$state.go('board', {type: 'sometType'})`

**OR**

From anchor you could use `ui-sref="board({type: 'sometType'})"` while create your url as `/borad/sometType`

Same thing would be follow when you wanted to insert board of `someType`

If you don't pass the `type` in `params` object then obviously the URL will result to `/board//insert`, for such thing you could define default value using `params` option of state.

**Config**

```
.state("board", {
    url:"/board/:type",
    templateUrl: "boardListPlain.jsp",
    controller: 'BoardController',
    params: {
        type: {
            value: 'defaultType' //if you don't mention the type, defaultType will become default.
        }
    }
    controllerAs : 'board'
})
 .state("board.insert", {
    url:"/insert",
    templateUrl: "boardInsert.html"
})
```

Comment: thanks! but I've already tried second solution without "default type" still my ui-view is not changing..